# UITableView expandable cell content not loaded / displayed properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipickerview

I have a `UITableView` with a Dynamic Prototype Cell that contains a few labels and an `UIPickerView`.
I defined an array as the default source for my `UIPickerView` and I also added the required methods:

```
var dataPicker =
[
    "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"
]

/*
// MARK: - UIPickerView methods
*/

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    print("JobVC > pickerView > numberOfComponents")

    //In this case this is always 1
    return pvComponents
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    print("JobVC > pickerView > numberOfRowsInComponent")

    return dataPicker.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    print("JobVC > pickerView > titleForRow")

    return dataPicker[row]
}
```

The `UIPickerView` data however changes depending on what row I select so I decided to set the `dataPicker` array data in my `didSelectRowAt` function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    print("JobVC > tableView > didSelectRowAtIndexPath")

    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        dataPicker =
            [
                "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"
            ]
        selectedCell = 0
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        dataPicker = []

        let currentYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())

        for year in 1970...currentYear
        {
            dataPicker.append( String(year) )
        }

        selectedCell = 1
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        dataPicker =
            [
                "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5", "Option 6"
            ]

        selectedCell = 2
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 3)
    {
        dataPicker =
            [
                "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"
            ]

        selectedCell = 3
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 4)
    {
        dataPicker =
            [
                "Option 1", "Option 2"
            ]

        selectedCell = 4
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 5)
    {
        dataPicker =
            [
                "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"
            ]

        selectedCell = 5
    }

    //Expandable cell  stuff

    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? JobExpandableCell
        else { return }

    switch cell.isExpanded
    {
        case true:
            self.expandedRows.remove(indexPath.row)
        case false:
            self.expandedRows.insert(indexPath.row)
    }

    cell.isExpanded = !cell.isExpanded

    self.tblJob.beginUpdates()
    self.tblJob.endUpdates()
}
```

Now, I did the same thing in another 3 cases and every time all went out OK. This time however the behaviour is a bit different.

If I start selecting rows starting from the one with the first one `(indexPath.row = 0)`, the cell expands and the `UIPickerView` shows the desired data set for every row.

If however I start selecting rows randomly or starting with the last one `(indexPath.row = 5)`, it shows no picker view until I select the first or the second row. From that point on, it starts showing it on every cell.

And this happens only the first time I access that screen (`ViewController`). If I start again from the bottom, there is no issue until I dismiss the VC or exit the app.

[image]

I checked and the `dataPicker[]` array if filled in with the desired data every time I tap row and there are no errors / warnings.

In fact, the only difference between this VC and the others where the same code works just fine is that in this case I have 6 rows and in all the others I have 2 or 3.

Any ideas? I've been trying for some time now to figure this out without any luck. And unfortunately I am not quite sure what to search for in this case.

LE: I think I figured out why this is happening. A `UITableView` only loads cells for the visible area, not all the cells available, since it is designed to display huge amounts of data and this will cause memory issues. The cell data gets loaded while the user scrolls.

However, in this case I assumed all the cells are visible while they are not since they are expandable cells and each one has 235px. This means only the 2 cells are loaded since only 2 cells can be displayed simultaneously.
The problem is I cannot scroll since only one cell is expanded at a time.

Any suggestions?